# Best way to change view (from form to results) in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to create a search form where a user queues up items, and then they click a search button to see their results.  The results are loaded in from a 3rd party API (through XHR), and while they're loading I want to show a progress wheel.  When the loading is done they'll be shown the results, and they'll be able to click a "back" button to get back to the search form (changes the view back to the original).

Note that this is all on one page.  There is no actual "submit", just a change in view to show the results.  It will be possible to refresh the results view and stay on the results view because I'll be using hashes to maintain state (like search/!#searchterms).

I'm an intermediate user of jQuery (read the docs and worked with it for about half a year now), but I've never done something like this and I was interested in what the best practices are.  Some specific things I was wondering:

- Should I be simply using toggle() to switch views? Or does this tend to look ebtter with some kind of animation?
- Are there some behind the scenes "pre-loading" tricks I should be doing to save time in updating the DOM?
- What's the common name for using hashtags to maintain state like this?  And where can I read more on doing that well with jQuery?
- Anything else I should know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking for basically a full featured web application.  You can piece together what you want with something like

- Ben Alman's BBQ http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/ (for maintaining state via hashes)
- jQuery templating https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl (for ... views)
- jQuery (to handle controller like logic)

Or you could learn something like Backbone.js or Spine.js or JavascriptMVC for added consistency.

There are many ways of handling caching with HTTP conditional requests and client side caching in memory or local storage.  I gave a talk recently on this and its viewable here:

http://loft.bocoup.com/tim-branyen-jquery-templates/

I'm not a particularly great speaker, but the slides and demo source is here:
http://talks.tabdeveloper.com/Advanced_jQuery_Templates/

Of course you could do this really basic... but I'd implore you to think more about what you're trying to do and pick the right solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a#search').click(function(){
  $('#search_form_overlay').show();
  $('#search_results').load('urls_to_api', { q: query_terms }, function() {
    $('#search_form_overlay').hide();
  });
});
```

And some answers:

Q: toggle() vs. animation
A: toggle is faster than animation, but which one look *better* ia a matter of taste.

Q. pre-loading
A. You are not updating the DOM with new resources (images), you are just showing a hidden div, so no pre-loading necessary.

Q. maintaining state
A. If by *maintain state* you are refering to each visitor's experience, you need to set and read cookies, but if you mean the state should be reproducible from the url, then you'd be using url fragment (`#something`). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906030/link-to-a-particular-slide-of-a-jquery-slider/5906108#5906108)'s a method I suggested for a similar situation; you can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: To clarify, the div with the search results has images

Comment: @babonk: If the images on the search result div are part of the result returned (and thus, unpredictable), no preloading can occur, but if you are using one or several fixed images, to section your results for instance, then preloading those will make displaying the results faster.